# add hyperlink text to specific rows ui-grid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have config.json file where i define columnDefs. I want to add hyperlink text to name field and redirect to page with information about that row. I try with some examples on SO but no success..

**config.json**

```
    "columnDefs":[
      {
        "name": "name"
      },
      {
        "name": "object_type_s"
      }
   ........
    ]
```

**controller**

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  columndDefs: config.columnDefs,
  ......
```

}

If i put cellTemplate in config file like this

```
{
"name": "name",
 "cellTemplate": "<a href="#">"
},
```

this will add hyperlink in all rows in my grid. I want for example to add hyperlink only to rows where

$scope.gridOptions.data.object_type == "SOMETHING"

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a name, it takes you a next page

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
            paginationPageSizes : [ 25, 50, 75 ],
            paginationPageSize : 25,
            enableColumnResizing : true,
            enableSorting : true,
            enableRowSelection : true,
            enableSelectAll : true,
            enableRowHeaderSelection: true,
            selectionRowHeaderWidth : 35,
            rowHeight : 35,
        showGridFooter : true,
```

The row template is used to get the selected row on an ui-grid

```
        rowTemplate : rowTemplate(),

        columnDefs : [
        {
        field : 'id',
        name : 'id',
        width: 200,
        },
        {   

            field : 'name',
            name  : 'name',
            width : 120,
            sort  : {
                priority : 0,
            },
            cellTemplate:'<div >' + '<a href="test.html">'+ '</a>' + '</div>',
        }
        } ],
          onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
              $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        }
    };
```

It gets a row, when we select a record

```
function rowTemplate() {
    return '<div ng-click="grid.appScope.rowDblClick(row);">' + ' <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell"  ui-grid-cell></div>' + '</div>';
}
```

when you click a row, you get a row using this method

```
$scope.rowDblClick = function(row) {
    console.log('The selected object id is : ', row.entity.id);
    console.log('The selected object nameis : ', row.entity.name);
};
```